# Lua sessions with dedicated "consoles" in multithreading environment

Tags: multithreading, lua

There are many Lua sessions (each one represented by its own lua_State) in an embedded multithreading program written in C++. Each Lua session has a dedicated "console" represented by a C++ object. This "console" is intended to provide session-specific stdin/stdout/stderr streams.

What's the right way to deliver such a "console" to the Lua session?
What's the right way to implement redirection of standard streams to/from such a console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a `userdata` into `io.stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` using

```
lua_getglobal(L, "io");
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, …); // or whatever value you want here
lua_setfield(L, 0, "stdin");
// rinse, repeat for stdout and stderr
```

Comment: I understand. The proposed solution works if my console object is compatible with the `FILE` structure. If it is not then perhaps further changes are required deep in Lua, aren't they?
Moreover, it's also necessary to make something with the `print` function, which is currently implemented using the `lua_writestring` and `lua_writeline` functions that don't have the `lua_State` available.

Comment: You should at least implement the necessary `read()` and `write()` operations (which you could do using a metatable). Note that this is even possible in lua itself – nothing stops you from overwriting io.stdin. While you're at it, you can overwrite _G["print"] (yup, forgot that one).